# is it bad-practice for unit-testing for different outcome?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

talking with a colleague about the following:

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "Notify if success only")]
[InlineData(false)]
[InlineData(true)]
public async Task IngestAsync(bool isSuccess)
{
    if (!isSuccess)
    {
        _transfererMock.Setup(t => t.TransferAsync(It.IsAny<Ingest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(Result.Fail("testError"));
    }

    var res = await _ingester.IngestAsync(new Ingest());

    Assert.Equal(res.IsSuccess, isSuccess);

    if (isSuccess)
    {
        _ingestNotifierMock.Verify(inn => inn.Notify(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Once);
    }
    else
    {
        _ingestNotifierMock.Verify(inn => inn.Notify(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Never);
    }
}
```

Is it a bad practice to test the outcome for different result or is this just fine?

Comment: This one is going to be largely opinion based, but a lot of people (myself included) will tell you that you should only verify one expected outcome per test, i.e. one for the expected failure case and another for the expected success case.

Comment: This is probably a better match for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's a balance here in terms of just how "different" a different outcome is.

At the most trivial, if we had a simple addition method then we'd of course want to know that given `2` and `3` as inputs it produced `5`, given `-2` and `9` it produced `7` and so on. We'd want to test it across a wide range of values paying particular attention both to those values that were likely in real code, edge cases (those on the border of overflow) and cases that had caused bugs in the past.

These are strictly "different outcomes", but they're all the same basic idea, so they're only barely "different".

Now, if this was a checked addition it would have throw an exception for the inputs `int.MaxValue` and `49`. That's a much more "different" different outcome.

If whether it was checked or not depended on some initial state, then the outcome for that previous case would differ depending on that state. That's an even more "different" type of "different outcome".

At some point it pretty much becomes a different thing being tested, and so should almost certainly have a different test.

Where we end up not being able to say much more than "primarily opinion-based" is just what that point is.

Personally, with the example I give above I would definitely consider the first case (simple addition giving the sum of the inputs) as the same test over the range of possible values. I'd probably consider the different initial states affecting the outcome as separate tests. I'm not sure whether I'd consider the middle case (some results cause overflow exceptions) as separate or the same and indeed when writing tests for System.Linq.Expressions I have considered analogous tests both ways, largely on the basis of what seemed more convenient. To me that case is so firmly in the camp of "primarily opinion-based" that I don't even have a consistent opinion on it myself.

Your example looks like the sort of case I'd consider significantly "different" a "different outcome" to have a separate test, but I might think otherwise if I had more knowledge of just what the code being tested did.

So in short, yes it's a good practice to have different tests for significantly different outcomes, but just how different "significantly different" is will often be cases where one could reasonably have different opinions.